# Criar um gráfico exploratório tipo peso~coleta filtrando tratamentos no R

Tags: r, graphics

Com a função tapply consigo saber os respectivos valores:

```
tapply(peso, list(coleta, tratamento), mean, na.rm=T)
tapply(peso, list(coleta, tratamento), sd, na.rm=T)
sd
    Biofloc  Control
A1       NA       NA
A2 20.69427 26.05011
A3 18.70375 29.34639
A4 19.22748 30.06533
A5       NA 31.81934
A6 24.03980 34.30186
A7 29.94012 39.98731
A8 29.29967 45.16424
```

Gostaria de saber como plotar isso no R, pois as funções utilizadas não me retornam o que quero.

Comment: Tente editar a sua pergunta, pois ela não está clara. A pergunta original afirma "as funções utilizadas não me retornam o que quero", mas não sabemos o que tu quer. O título da pergunta fala em "gráfico exploratório tipo peso ~ coleta filtrando tratamentos", mas o que significa isso? É um gráfico de dispersão? Boxplot? É um gráfico com médias e desvios padrão?

Comment: Certo. 
Eu tenho um conjunto de dados que tem as seguintes variáveis, peso, coleta e tratamento. Quero um gráfico que me mostre a média de peso por coleta e tratamento, pode ser barplot, boxplot desde que eu consiga discriminar a média de pesos por coleta e tratamento. 
Quando digo que as funções que tentei utilizar, falo sobre "subset", tentando filtrar dentro de um boxplot. Ex: boxplot(peso~coleta, subset = tratamento =="Biofloc") aí ela me retorna 1 gráfico apenas com essas variáveis e para este tratamento em específico e quero os tudo em um gráfico só.

Answer (score 2):

Penso em dois tipos de gráficos para a sua situação, mas todos ao redor de pacotes diferentes do que você usuou, (base R).

Mas segue como eu faria, pode ser que lhe ajude!

Primeiro gero alguns dados que parecem ter a mesma estrutura que os seus:

```
library(tidyverse)
n <-100
set.seed(42)
theme_set(theme_minimal())
tb <- 
    tibble(
    coleta = map_chr(1:5 , ~paste('A', . , sep = '')) %>% 
             rep(20),
    tratamento = rbinom(size = 1, n = 100, prob = 0.5),
    peso = rnorm(mean = tratamento*0.03, 100),
    tratamento_char = tratamento %>% paste('tratamento', .)
)
```

A primeira maneira, é usando um `facet` para cada tratamento, que eu não gosto muito no caso de tratamento em si, pois você não vê o efeito de uma mudança diretamente:

```
tb %>% 
    group_by(coleta, tratamento_char) %>% 
    summarise(avg = mean(peso)) %>% 
    ggplot(data = . , aes(x = coleta, y = avg)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ tratamento_char)
```

[image: método 1]

O segundo método é mais minimalista, mas passa bem a mensagem, pois facilita a comparação dos tratamentos em uma coleta:

```
tb %>% 
    group_by(coleta, tratamento_char) %>% 
    summarise(avg = mean(peso)) %>% 
    ggplot(data = . , aes(x = coleta, y = avg)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = tratamento_char, 
                   pch = tratamento_char), size = 2)
```

[image: método 2]

O último método, é o meu preferido, pois facilita a comparação entre os grupos e mostra a tendência do todo no experimento.

```
tb %>% 
    group_by(coleta, tratamento_char) %>% 
    summarise(avg = mean(peso))  %>% 
    ggplot(data = . , aes(x = tratamento_char, y = avg)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = coleta)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = coleta, color = coleta), 
              alpha = 0.2, 
              size = 2.5)
```

[image: método 3]

Comment: Boa tarde. 
Muito obrigado pela ajuda, ainda não tinha pegado pra estudar o ggplot2, já ouvi e vi gráficos muito bons feitos com esse pacote. Agora não tem muita escapatória.